# Where does the "Lyrical" part come from?

Tags: nanoha

I've been wondering where the **"Lyrical"** part of *Magical Girl **Lyrical** Nanoha* comes from. To the best of my knowledge, none of the Magic the characters use seem to be remotely music based, and even when the writers tried to step away from the "Magical Girl" aspect, they still kept the *Lyrical* part in *Magical Record **Lyrical** Nanoha Force*.

Is there some meaning to the word *Lyrical* that I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a lot of this stuff, its probably just english that sounds cool - also Nanoha does use it in her activation key (which is barely ever used).

As for where it originally came from, Nanoha itself is a spinoff from Triangle Heart, a VN series about the rest of the Takamachi family, who are badass bodyguards - you can see the original prototype here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_RBghAfiW8